# WAMP Server's Apache Service Not Starting in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, apache-http-server, php, webserver, wamp

I have a problem starting the Apache Service in WAMP Server, when i test port 80, I get the following message on the console

```
Your port 80 is actually used by :
Server: Microsoft -HTTPAPI/2.0
```

Things i did:

used netstat -aon from the command prompt to check what is running on port 80 and i get something with a PID of 4.

This PID of 4 corresponds to a file named - ntoskrnl (NT Kernel & System) in C:\Windows\System32

How do I go about solving this issue?

Comment: A common error is running Skype. It too uses port 80 and won't let wamp start up.

Comment: I had already unchecked that option in Skype before, but no luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found out the culprit, it was the SQL Server 2012 reporting and analysis services that were using port 80.

I opened up services.msc from the command prompt, disabled both these services and WAMP Server works perfectly now with no localhost problem.

Thanks to all those who provided the answers to this question, they were right but unfortunately all the solutions presented had already been applied in my case.

Comment: Select this as the correct answer to show it as answered. It is the correct way of doing it here even if you don't get any rep yourself.

Comment: Hey, thanks for reminding this , i was totally unaware of it. Thank You... :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 Browse to your httpd.conf under the Apache menu and find the line "Listen 80"

  Just change it to something like "Listen 8088" and restart Wampserver.

  If everything is fine, your little Wamp Icon on the systray should be white and  
   everything should be good to go.
```

Comment: This feels like: instead of fixing it just sweep it under the carpet.

Comment: Is there any way to fix it rather than changing or making it listen to a different port?

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like, your system is already running IIS server which is using port 80.

You can disable it by going to Control Panel -> Uninstall Programs -> Turn Windows Features On or Off -> uncheck Internet Information Services

You should then try restarting your Wamp server (and your computer as well, if needed).

It might also be worth checking the entries in your HOSTS file located at

> WINDOWS\System32\drivers\etc

There should be just one entry for your localhost i.e:

> 127.0.0.1 localhost

Comment: Hi, IIS is unchecked by default, even the host file has only 1 entry as you specified. Any other solution?

Comment: This is quite a bit of research and should help you :

http://graftalks.blogspot.in/2012/11/how-to-use-wamp-server-on-windows-8.html

Comment: And here is one more solution that might work for you:

http://www.yetmorestuff.net/index.php/2011/08/18/what-is-using-port-80-on-your-computer/

Sorry I cannot test these, as I am not in Windows 8 currently.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was Skype. This is how to find out:

Use netstat- aon to see what PID is using port 80.

Use tasklist to see what process hides behind that PID.